# Qt: Child QObject during deconstruction?

Tags: c++, qt

When the parent QObject is deconstructed, when will its children be deconstructed?
For example:

```
QChild* child = new QChild(master);
```

when we delete master; the master's destructor ~Master() will be called before or after the child's destructor? What's order here?

Comment: Correct answer is "inside", not before nor after. @Chernobyl provided a complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~QObject()` will delete all children, accurate order you can find in source code. Consider [Qt source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0:src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L977):

```
QObject::~QObject()
{
    Q_D(QObject);//now we have d-pointer
    //...
    //another code here, which for example disconnect everything
    if (!d->children.isEmpty())
        d->deleteChildren();
    //...
}
```

Where [`deleteChildren()`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0:src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L1970) is:

```
void QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren()
{
    const bool reallyWasDeleted = wasDeleted;
    wasDeleted = true;
    // delete children objects
    // don't use qDeleteAll as the destructor of the child might
    // delete siblings
    for (int i = 0; i < children.count(); ++i) {
        currentChildBeingDeleted = children.at(i);
        children[i] = 0;
        delete currentChildBeingDeleted;
    }
    children.clear();
    currentChildBeingDeleted = 0;
    wasDeleted = reallyWasDeleted;
}
```

See also: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/execution-order-of-constructor-and-destructor-in-inheritance/

Another example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class Child: public QObject
{
public:

    Child(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {}

    ~Child()
    {
       qDebug("child destroyed");
    }
};

class Parent: public QObject
{
public:

    Parent(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {}

    ~Parent()
    {
       qDebug("do something here");
       qDebug("parent destroyed");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Parent *parent = new Parent;

    Child *child1 = new Child(parent);
    Child *child2 = new Child(parent);
    //do something
    delete parent;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
do something here
parent destroyed
child destroyed
child destroyed
```

If you will write `~Parent(){delete A; delete B;}`, then as you can see from output `A` and `B` will be deleted first and child objects will be deleted earlier.

**Why?**

[Because of rule which I suggested you earlier](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/execution-order-of-constructor-and-destructor-in-inheritance/)

```
Inside Base constructor
Inside Derived constructor
Inside Derived destructor
Inside Base destructor
```

which in our case is translated to:

```
Inside QObject constructor
Inside Parent constructor
Inside Parent destructor 
Inside QObject destructor//don't forget that only ~QObject delete children, not a ~Parent
```

Comment: Say if ~Master() is like ~Master(){delete A; delete B;} will child be deleted before or after the delete of A and B?

Comment: @Nyaruko See my edit please, I added extremely detailed description, I think all is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Execution of the parent's destructor will begin before the child destructor, and will finish after the child has been destroyed.